# Check hash table contains value or not

Tags: powershell, process, hashtable

I use PowerShell to execute SQL query to get computer process id and return hash tale below:

```
$processId
5068
6176
7240
7632
```

Now, I use: `$processId -contains 5068` to check this value exist in `$processId` or not.

My expected is `true` but it return `false`.

I don't know why. Welcome all answer.

Result $processId | Get-Member:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the results of `$processId | Get-Member`, please?

Comment: `-contains` only works on an array, so if this is a hash as you say, this method cannot work

Comment: The picture isn't of any use,  [gvee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610022/gvee) asked for a `$processId | Get-Member` (not a `[Result $processId | Get-Member] [1]`, this is clearly a string. B.t.w. what does `Result` do? is this a Custom cmdlet?). The following would probably better clear up what `$processId` really contains: `$processId | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 16):

On a hashtable, you can check for existing items using the `ContainsKey()` method. For example:

```
$processId.ContainsKey(5068)
```

Comment: That is because `$processId` is not hashtable, as mentioned in your question (it's a string).  How is it created?  Get more information on using hashtables here: [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6)

Comment: So, `$processId` is an array of strings, not a hashtable.  However, your original test should have worked whether they were strings or integers.  Is it possible the strings contain extra spaces at the end, or other 'hidden' characters?  Try this to see if it helps:  `$processId.Trim() -contains 5068`

Comment: Thank you so much. $processId.Trim() -contains 5068 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It works fine for me:

```
PS C:\> $processId = 5068, 5068, 7240, 7632
PS C:\> $processId -contains 5068
True
```

In other words, your array (`$processId`) is either not a array or doesn't contain integers (or strings).
If it really concerns a hashtable as in the title/description, it is either:

```
$processId.Keys -contains 5068
```

or:

```
$processId.Values -contains 5068
```

(depending on whether it concerns the `keys` or the `values`)